# Can py.test support multiple -k options?

Tags: pytest

Can py.test supports multiple -k options?
Each testcase belongs to a particular group such as _eventnotification or _interface, etc.
Is it possible to run test cases that belong to either one or both at the same time?
ie, run testcases that has _eventnotification or _interface in the name at the same time.
I tried the following and only the testcases with _interface were executed.
If that is not supported, is there another way to do this?

py.test -k "_eventnotification" -k "_interface"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bad news: pytest-2.3.3 does not support it.

The good news: i took your question as an opportunity to finally enhance "-k" behaviour, so that you can use "not", "or", "end" etc, see the [extended -k example][1].  It works now like "-m" except that it matches on (substrings of) test names, not markers. You can use this in-development pytest version with "pip install -i http://pypi.testrun.org -U pytest".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. After I installed the update, py.test -s -v --durations=20 -k '_disk or _eventnotification' worked as expected. Now I am able to run tests that has either keywords in the test name. py.test is working out very well for my test automation effort for Nimbus Data.